# VBA - List of all controls in project

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I got 424 error "object required" for the code below. Objective of code below is to print a list of all controls in the VBA project.  Why am getting this 424 error?

```
Public Sub List_Controls_All_Userforms()

    '<<<< Ojective:  I want to create a list of all controls in my project, including Userform.Names.


    Dim individualUserform As Object
    Dim controlItem As Control
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheets("TabNames").Range("H1:H50")   '<<<<< 50 userform names.
        Set individualUserform = cell.Value               '<<<<< Error 424 object required. <<< Calling each form by name like this is wrong??
        For Each controlItem In individualUserform.Controls
          rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
          Sheets("TabControls").Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value = individualUserform.Name & "." & controlItem.Name
        Next controlItem
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Screenshots added again, this time in my original text, rather than in Rajesh's reply (screenshots didn't upload there for some reason).

Comment: I think you have missed assigning USER Form to code,, should like ,,  `Set individualUserform = UserFormName`     then in next line,,                                                                        
 `Load frmUserFormName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I'm afraid that's not correct. However you can use/loop the `VBComponents` collection in the Workbook's `VBProject`:

---

If you want to loop through your specified range, because you wrote down the names of the UserForms try:

```
Public Sub List_Controls_All_Userforms()

Dim controlItem As Control
Dim rowNumber As Long
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("TabNames").Range("H1:H50")
    For Each controlItem In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(cell).Designer.Controls
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
        Sheets("TabControls").Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value = cell & "." & controlItem.Name
    Next controlItem
Next cell

End Sub
```

---

If you don't want to write down all your UserForm names in a range and loop that, you could also try to loop the `VBComponents` collection and check their `.Type` (3 = UserForm) like so:

```
Public Sub List_Controls_All_Userforms()

Dim controlItem As Control
Dim rowNumber As Long
Dim obj as object

For Each obj In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    If obj.Type = 3 Then
        For Each controlItem In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(obj.Name).Designer.Controls
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
            Sheets("TabControls").Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value = obj.Name & "." & controlItem.Name
        Next controlItem
    End If
Next obj

End Sub
```

---

> **Note** that as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548104/9758194) answer that this requires an additional security permission > Excel Options > Trust Centre > Macro Settings > Trust access to the VBA Project object model.

Comment: Thank you JvdV!!  I have learned something new!

Comment: Yes, thank you JvdV… Your code works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*You may use this VBA code to fix the issue:*

```
Sub ListControls() 
    Dim lCntr As Long 
    Dim aCtrls() As Variant 
    Dim ctlLoop As MSForms.Control 

    
    For Each ctlLoop In YourForm.Controls 
        lCntr = lCntr + 1: Redim Preserve aCtrls(1 To lCntr) 
    
        aCtrls(lCntr) = TypeName(ctlLoop)&":"&ctlLoop.Name 
    Next ctlLoop 
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aCtrls)).Value = Application.Transpose(aCtrls) 
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Replace `YourForm` with real Form Name also, Sheet Name & Cell reference.
- This code adds all controls to `Sheet 1`.

## **Edited:**

*You can use this VBA code in case you want to list controls from all User Forms in current project.*

```
Sub test1()

Dim i, k As Long
Dim dForm As UserForm
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim c()
Dim fmBCMcontact    
  
    Set dForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("fmBCMcontact").Designer
  i = 0
  For Each ctl In fmBCMcontact.Controls
    ReDim Preserve c(i)
    c(i) = ctl.Name
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve c(i)
    c(i) = TypeName(ctl)
    Sheets("TabResult").Cells(i, 1).Value = c(i)   
    i = i + 1
  Next
  
End Sub
```

Comment: The whole point is to loop multiple userforms.

Comment: Hi Rajesh - I ran the code exactly as above, but got an error "variable not defined" for:  fmBCMcontact.  How do I define this variable:  fmBCMcontact…?

Comment: @SofiaEd,, it `"fmBCMcontact"` has been already been defined above,, add `MS Form object Library` at `Tool  & References`.

Comment: Already added library... please see screenshots?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SofiaEd,, where is Screen Shot?

Comment: Rajesh -- Added to your reply box, but apparently didn't work, so just added to my original box (original question box) above.  Please let me know, I want to understand for future use.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @SofiaEd,, nice you have added correct one ,,at  my end Macro is working properly & getting all control's name in Sheet!!

Comment: Well, then I wonder what is the problem?  Furthermore, will this problem impact my other codes?  huhuhu…. I may have to circle back to this one soon.  Added correct library, but got the error as you can see, weird!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98321/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-sofiaed).

Comment: @SofiaEd The proper syntax would be: `For Each ctl In dForm.Controls`. However this code will only loop the controls on one specified userform and not loop all userforms in your project. In fact @RajeshS, you can drop `Dim fmBCMcontact` and just use: `Set dForm = fmBCMcontact`

Comment: Yes got it now, thank you very much both!!  Rajesh, thank you!!  JvdV, thank you!!